# Blender 2.79b Crashes High Sierra MacBook

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, gpu, opengl, osx

I'll try to make this as short as possible, but it's gonna be long. Problem: Blender 2.79b crashes my early 2011 MacBook 15-inch running High Sierra during viewport rendering. Operating theater: 2.2 GHz Intel Core Duo i7. 16 Gb RAM. Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB and an AMD Radeon HD 6750M (automatic switching is on). Not using GPU render setting in Blender. 750Gb hard drive and 1 Tb external Time Machine backup drive. **Problem:** Computer crashes as mentioned. Runs Adobe Creative Cloud, Microsoft Office, Chrome, Safari and Unity without problem. Installed High Sierra in Fall 2018 and has not been a problem until second week of February 2019. Produces crash, boot loop and White Screen of Death (WSoD) **Things I've tried:**

1. Ran disk first aid--report said disk OK.
2. Re-installed OS--went without a hitch, but problem remains.
3. Command + R to enter recover--process goes to WSoD just before reaching list of recovery options.
4. Command + Option + R to enter internet recovery--goes to WSoD just before reaching list of recovery options.
5. Command + Option + R + P to reset PRAM--works but doesn't solve my problem.
6. Shift + Option + Command + Start to reset SMC--works but doesn't solve my problem.
7. D + Start to run Apple hardware diagnostics--no problems found.
8. Shift + Start to enter Safe Mode--it doesn't.
9. Option + Start to enter recovery mode via attached Time Machine backup drive--enabled me to run disk first aid and re-install OS. Still crashes.
   **Current status.** After many, many boot attempts, I reached my login-in screen, and that's why I am able to post this. Has anyone had this problem? Solutions? Thanks.

Comment: No user land tool should be able to crash a computer in a way that you mentioned. Drivers on the other hand have more hardware control and problems there could result in a crash. Two graphic controllers with auto switching could be the problem for instance. Try disable the automatic switching.
If you still believe this to be a Blender problem, report it as a bug.

Comment: Thank you, Jackdaw. I really appreciate your time and experience. I have tried disabling the automatic switching feature, but it does not prevent the crash. At first, I was using the OpenGL feature in Blender to access the AMD Radeon card, thinking that might enhance rendering. When the app began crashing, I switched that option to "none" and got the same results. Out of curiosity, what remedy would you recommend where drivers are concerned? Thanks again.

Comment: High Sierra is still crashing while I use Blender 2.79b (and only Blender takes it down). I have cleaned my MacBook throughly, including caches, language files, etc. All other applications operate without problem. However, when I return to a project I started last week, the whole system crashes into a boot loop—usually when I'm orbiting the model I'm building. What hidden code Kamikaze do I have that won't let me use Blender? And I LOVE Blender. I need it to work. Help.